# How to use double paste in assign?

Tags: r, function, user-defined-functions

I'm working with different countries datasets downloaded from [OEC](http://atlas.media.mit.edu/en/)'s API.

I'm dividing my work in two steps:

1. Getting and cleaning a certain dataset. OK
2. Create a function to download any dataset. *I'm stuck in this part*

For the first part I did run

```
chile2013_df <- as.data.frame(fromJSON("http://atlas.media.mit.edu/hs92/export/2013/chl/all/show/"))
keep <- c("data.hs92_id", "data.import_val", "data.export_val")
chile2013_df <- chile2013_df[keep]
```

and that is ok and works, but if I want to create a function, let's say

```
country_data <- function(COUNTRYCODE, YEAR) {
assign(paste(COUNTRYCODE, YEAR, "_raw", sep=""), as.data.frame(fromJSON(paste("http://atlas.media.mit.edu/hs92/export/",YEAR,"/",COUNTRYCODE,"/all/show/", sep=""))), envir = globalenv());
assign(c("keep"), c("data.hs92_id", "data.import_val", "data.export_val");
assign(paste(COUNTRYCODE, YEAR, "_clean", sep=""), paste(COUNTRYCODE, YEAR, "_raw[keep]", sep=""));
envir = globalenv())
}
```

Then if I run

```
country_data("per","2010")
```

The raw file will be perfect but then `per2010_clean` will look as a text "per2010_raw[keep]"

How can I make `per2010_raw[keep]` effective? many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
keep <- c("data.hs92_id", "data.import_val", "data.export_val")
country_data <- function(COUNTRYCODE, YEAR) {
    weblink <- paste0("http://atlas.media.mit.edu/hs92/export/",YEAR,"/",COUNTRYCODE,"/all/show/")
    rawdat <- as.data.frame(fromJSON(file=weblink))
    cleandat <- rawdat[keep]
    return(list(raw=rawdat, clean=cleandat))
} #end country_data
```

Then you can mapply for your pairs of (country, year). Ideally, dont use the country and year in your variable names as it can grow pretty unwieldy and unscalable after a while

```
#pulling data
alldat <- mapply(function(x, y) list(country_data(x, y)), c("per","chl"), c(2010, 2013))
names(alldat) <- paste0(c("per","chl"), c(2010, 2013))

#accessing data
alldat[["chl2013"]]$raw
alldat[["chl2013"]]$clean
```

Answer (score -1):

Your approach is useful, thanks. Changing a little of your code I'm getting something closer to what I wanted.

```
keep <- c("data.hs92_id", "data.import_val", "data.export_val")
country_data <- function(COUNTRYCODE, YEAR) {
weblink <- paste0("http://atlas.media.mit.edu/hs92/export/",YEAR,"/",COUNTRYCODE,"/all/show/")
clean <<- as.data.frame(fromJSON(weblink))[keep]
}
country_data("per", 2010)
```

Comment: Do not write functions with side effects. Do not use `<<-` or `assign`.

Comment: One reason to heed Roland's advice (with which I completely agree) is that if you had any item named `clean` in your workspace, the call to `country_data` above would wipe it out and replace it. Possibly that is what you would expect, but it's not what most R programmers would want to occur. We generally only want that to occur when we use `<-`. Perhaps if you renamed it to "replace_clean_with_new_country_data" it wouldn't be so worrisome for those of us who do functional programming.